# .htaccess force https, non www and parse to index

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi there I'm working with .htaccess to set a couple of rules but my knowledge of .htaccess is rather limited. I've been searching only to find parts of what I need and where unable to make it work.

Currently I use the following rules to force all links to the index.php:

```
# if requested url does not exist pass it as path info to index.php
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

My issue is to combine this with the following rules:

```
1. Force http -> https
 2. force www  -> non www
 3. Apply the top rules
```

As an example:
http://wwww.example.com  -> https://example.com

I hope this makes sense; I've got quite some issues with the mod rewrite rules.
So thanks in advance ...

Comment: No, it doesn’t make sense to try and do this in one single step. The redirect to the index.php in an _internal_ one, whereas the redirect to HTTPS and non-www of course has to be an external one.

Answer (score 0):

This must be added to your vritualhost config

```
<virtualhost *:80>   
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
    RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This should be added to your virtualhost ssl config

```
<virtualhost *:443>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This should work.

Comment: but isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not the OP :)

Comment: yeah just realized. But this is what OP is looking for I guess. force non-www to https and get his rules to work lol

Comment: Well currently not in the position to test it, i will check if this work and let you know!  Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: As i already thought this is causing an infinite loop of some sort.
I'm going to dig further on how to tackle this. 

Anyhow thanks! :)

Comment: check the answer again

Comment: By applying the following rule at the top it sort of works 
as this prevents an infiniteloop


`Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !myhostname.ext`

Comment: but your second rule must be added to your SSL configuration otherwise it won't work since it will be working on http only.